# How to create admin section to node.js / express.js application

Tags: node.js, express, content-management-system, admin, secure-coding

To be right up front, I am still (I feel like) relatively new to building in Node/Express/MongoDB/Mongoose so please excuse if these questions may sound silly.

So I am trying to create a custom Admin section for a small web application I am working on that will allow me to, of course, add small bits of content, manage that content etc. I understand there are a lot of frameworks out there like Keystone.js and even Strapi to make quick API's but I just want to tackle this from the ground up. So with this comes a few questions...

1) Admin file structure for an Express.js application. Should I keep admin files completely separate from my actual app? Further more, if I do this, how could I keep the 2 different servers (1 for the app and 1 for the admin area) under one domain and use them interchangeably ta access one or the other? I currently have the app built with routes going to an admin section that is still part of my overall application (probably not a good way of building I am sure).

My current structure:

```
app.js
models
  |-- admin-model
  |-- additional-models*
public
  |-- css
  |-- js
  |-- img
routes
  |-- application-routes.js
  |-- admin-routes.js
```

If I move it to a structure like so:

```
app.js
models
  |-- admin-model
  |-- additional-models*
public
  |-- css
  |-- js
  |-- img
routes
  |-- application-routes.js
admin
  |-- admin-app.js
  |-- routes
        |-- admin-routes.js
  |-- public
        |-- admin-css
        |-- admin-js
        |-- admin-img
```

How would I keep the routes working or even more so, use the two separate app.js files?

2) (Not a question really but figured I'd list it) I want to try and keep this all under one domain. I don't foresee this application being a behemoth and personally, would love to use this mini CMS for future applications as well. I want to make very similar to what I see WordPress' open source CMS doing for their system (although I could be very wrong and again excuse my newby self). They just have an admin section to the same domain.

All in all, how would I go about successfully creating an admin section to a small CMS from scratch. Again, I know there are options already out there but I have a huge idea I would love to implement and there is no better way to learn than jumping straight in. Thanks for hearing me out on this and further more, putting up with silly questions!

Comment: The question isn't well-suited for SO. But 1) It's up to you but it makes sense to keep it a separate app (project) if there's a borderline between f/end and b/end 2) you can use a subdomain for b/end, that's how it's usually done

Comment: Fait enough, not sure how this doesn't fit Stack Overflow but I will respect it. But keeping it in a separate app, how would one switch back and forth between server files with the same domain?

Comment: It falls into 'opinion-based' category. This sort of questions isn't allowed on SO anymore. I'm not sure what 'switch back and forth between server files' means. You have two different Express servers at different ports. One is bound to www.example.com:80, another one is bound to admin.example.com:80. This is specific to your web server configuration (Nginx or whatever).

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Had no idea where to ask this and found other similar questions like this that must of been before the policy shift. I see what your saying now. But I am trying to keep everything under one domain similar to Keystone.js CMS. Make simple and easy to install. I guess this comes with security risks though but I would need to weigh the pros and cons.

Comment: **** Edit to the above **** I now understand it is the same domain but simply adding a prefix to the URL like admin.yourdomainname.com. I apologize and honestly had no idea you could do this (like I said, newby here and I swear it is like drinking through a firehose). Thanks for your insight!